# Setting up a multi-broker cluster for KAFKA and trying to kill the Leader Broker

Tags: apache-kafka

I am following the official KAFKA guide for setting up a multi-broker cluster. That works as we can see this when the issued command below is run:

```
[cloudera@quickstart kafka_2.11-1.1.0]$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe -- 
zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
Topic:my-replicated-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
     Topic: my-replicated-topic Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 2,0,1
```

However, I would like to kill the leader Broker as per the guide - which is node 2, but I cannot find the pid in order to kill the leader. I can only find 1 of the 3 nodes. What have I missed?

```
[cloudera@quickstart kafka_2.11-1.1.0]$ ps aux | grep server-1.properties
 cloudera 15203  0.1  0.1 528140 20588 ?        S    04:11   0:10 gedit /home/cloudera/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/server-1.properties
 cloudera 20833  0.0  0.0 103312   936 pts/7    S+   05:51   0:00 grep server-1.properties

 [cloudera@quickstart kafka_2.11-1.1.0]$ ps aux | grep server-2.properties
  cloudera 20837  0.0  0.0 103308   912 pts/7    S+   05:51   0:00 grep server-2.properties
```

I can find broker 1 but not broker 2.

So I cannot kill the leader Broker.

But there has to be a twist here. Running Centos 6 BTW.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your server.properties file you must have defined the port and the broker id before running the brokers so why you need to find the pid as that you have only given that? You do kafka-server-start ../confit/server.properties to run a broker

Comment: I am following exactly the KAFKA Tutorial from KAFKA and am reasonably confident I have not made a mistake - not following

Comment: you setup cluster with 3 nodes in one server?

Comment: yes, as per kafka quickstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we run the broker we do

```
kafka-server-start ../config/server.properties 
//by default the value of brokerid is 0 and port is 9092

Create one more server1.properties with brokerid 1 and port 9093 //given nothing is already running on port 9093 and do

kafka-server-start ../config/server1.properties
```

While running more than one broker you have to have more than one server.properties config or file. In the `server.properties` file you have fields as `brokerid` by default it is 0 while running more than one you will have to change the brokerid since we can’t have 2 brokers with same brokerid

And you have one more field in server.properties which describe on which port your server (broker) will run which is port by default the value of the port is 9092 and while running the other broker you will have to change the value of port too as we can’t have the 2 processes running on the same port.

If you want a GUI based tool to see your kafka cluster I would suggest you to use kafka-tool which will give you the whole picture of your cluster how many brokers do you have what is the properties of these brokers and how many partitions do you have which broker is leader for which partition everting.

Comment: I got no message stating an error as you can see - it tells there are 3 replicas. Surely that means OK, otherwise would have got a bind error etc.

Comment: Then with the broker Id = 2 you must have specified the port just kill that process!!

Comment: Missing something ... please elaborate as I followed the KAFKA Tut exactly and is seems to make sense

Comment: You are following the QuickStart? For apache kafka?

Comment: What is the error when you do taskkill /pid 912 /f make sure the command you are writing has no extra spaces?

Comment: Yes I am following that - it all works fine otherwise although some aspects are of course very simple - seems more reliable that Confluent stuff

Comment: I could not kill that Leader as I could not find pid

Comment: Can you please try ls /proc/port number what you have defined in server.properties or try pidof command

Comment: too advance for me. pidof not sure what to pass in as parameter

Comment: this is an odd issue imho

Comment: indeed with 3 config files as in the quickstart - does the output above not prove that?

Comment: @thebluephantom pidof then the name of the service for example pidof chrome

Comment: I am wondering whether stand-alone mode has something to do with?

Comment: Think not when re-checking.